# nggettext_compile does not extract any strings from my .PO file

Tags: angular-gettext

I have a file `po/el.po` containing translations:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2015-07-01 10:49+0000\n"
"Language: el\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;\n"
"X-Generator: Weblate 2.2\n"

#: static/src/partials/layout/header.html:17
#, fuzzy
msgid "About"
msgstr "σχετικά με"

#: static/src/partials/layout/header.html:19
#, fuzzy
msgid "Admin"
msgstr "διαχειριστής"

[[SNIP]]
```

I've taken the Gruntfile config straight from the [documentation](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/compile/).

```
nggettext_compile: {
        all: {
                  files: {
                        'static/src/js/app/translations.js': [
                                'po/*.po'
                        ]
                }
        }
}
```

`grunt --verbose` shows that it finds `po/el.po`, and creates `static/src/js/app/translations.js`

```
Running "nggettext_compile:all" (nggettext_compile) task
Verifying property nggettext_compile.all exists in config...OK
Files: po/el.po -> static/src/js/app/translations.js
Options: (none)
Reading po/el.po...OK
Writing static/src/js/app/translations.js...OK

Done, without errors.
```

However, the resulting `static/src/js/app/translations.js` contains an empty list of translations:

```
angular.module('gettext').run(['gettextCatalog', function (gettextCatalog) {
/* jshint -W100 */
    gettextCatalog.setStrings('el', {});
/* jshint +W100 */
}]);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

nggettext_compile does not include translations flagged as "fuzzy", and since I'm just setting this up ready for our translators, all the translations are machine-generated, and hence flagged as "fuzzy"...